# Retry OpmisticLockException with Hypersistence Utils library does not work

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, guice, optimistic-locking

I have used this example to implement `OptimisticLockException` handling:
[How to retry JPA transactions after an OptimisticLockException](https://vladmihalcea.com/optimistic-locking-retry-with-jpa/)

Dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.hypersistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hypersistence-utils-hibernate-55</artifactId>
    <version>${hypersistence-utils.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I have annotated the method which may receive OptimisticLockException:

```
@Retry(times = 10, on = OptimisticLockException.class)
public void modifySomething(){...}
```

However, when RollbackException/OptimisticLockException/StaleStateException occurs, I get a stack trace, but the method is not retried.

I use it with Guice 4.1.0. Should I bind it somewhere or write the method interceptor?

How to add AOP aspect?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the [`RetryAspect`](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils/blob/a31d72f2895e68e5fc87618a1026797d142cddfd/hypersistence-utils-hibernate-55/src/main/java/io/hypersistence/utils/spring/aop/RetryAspect.java) to your Spring configuration.

If you are using Guice, you have to create a similar Aspect because the one coming with Hypersistence Utils is only working with Spring.

In Spring, the configuration is very easy; you can do it like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = {
        "io.hypersistence.utils.spring.aop"
    }
)
public class RetryAspectConfiguration {

}
```